# How do I use python-CFFI to wrap the random variates generation functions in GSL?

Tags: python, random, cython, gsl, python-cffi

The difficulty I'm having is that the random variate (RV) generation functions in GSL require a pointer to a special struct `gsl_rng` as one of their arguments, such as

```
double gsl_rng_uniform (const gsl_rng * r);  // generate uniform RVs
double gsl_ran_gaussian (const gsl_rng * r, double sigma); // generate Gaussian RVs
```

Since all the RV generation functions share the same "source of randomness", which is represented by `gsl_rng * r`, a typical use pattern in C is to construct a `gsl_rng * r` upfront, and then make subsequent calls of various random variates generation functions, and deconstruct `r` in the end.

I'd like to use CFFI in python to make native C calls to speed up a Monte Carlo simulation program. The question I have now is how to appropriately "hide" the C pointer `gsl_rng * r` from python side, while making sure it is shared by all the RV generation functions that I'd call from python?

P.S. I know how to achieve this in Cython like the following:

```
## demo.pyx    --- a Cython file
## declaration of C functions and structs
cdef extern from "math.h":
double exp(double)

cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_rng.h":
    ctypedef struct gsl_rng:
        pass
    ctypedef struct gsl_rng_type:
        pass

    const gsl_rng_type * gsl_rng_default    
    gsl_rng * gsl_rng_alloc (const gsl_rng_type *)
    void gsl_rng_free (gsl_rng *)
    double gsl_rng_uniform (const gsl_rng *)


cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_randist.h":
    double gsl_ran_gaussian (const gsl_rng *, double)

## define a python function that generates RVs
def foo(double sigma):
    cdef:         
        int i;
        double s;
        const gsl_rng_type * T = gsl_rng_default;
        gsl_rng * r = gsl_rng_alloc(T)

    for i in range(10):
        s += gsl_ran_gaussian(r, sigma) + gsl_rng_uniform(r);  ## share r
    gsl_rng_free(r) 
    return s
```

Comment: Would it be possible to "mock" the problem by making a C file with the same (or preferably a subset of the) interface? This would make it easier to experiment on.

Comment: On closer reading, I'm not sure what you're talking about when you mention hiding the pointer. What exactly is tripping you up on the CFFI side?

Comment: @Veedrac My major problem is that since there is no analog of the struct pointer `gsl_rng *r` in python, if I simply copy the signature of the function, say `double gsl_rng_uniform (const gsl_rng * r);`, in `ffi.cdef()`, how would I pass argument and call this function in python?

Comment: You need to wrap the pointers to your struct in a Python object. See this question regarding the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23547259