# How to wrap C struct using Cython?

Tags: python, c, cython

I'm trying to wrap a custom C struct to use in Python.

```
#somecode.pyx
cdef extern from "example.c":

    cdef struct some_struct:
        pass

    void some_function(const char *filename, some_struct *ret)

cdef class wrap_some_struct:
    cdef some_struct *_ptr
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._ptr = NULL

def wrap_some_function(const char *filename, wrap_some_struct ret):
    some_function(filename, ret)
```

This will give the error

> Cannot convert Python object to 'some_struct *'

How should I implement this correctly?

Comment: I don't use Cython, but does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545875 answer your question?

Comment: No, it did not. I want to write an external function (from the wrap class) to use the wrapped struct in Python.

Comment: As explained in the duplicate: for the call of the c-function you should use `ret._ptr` and not `ret` which is a Python object